How to receive opcua event on the client side?
I have a server which trigger an event.
On the client side I want to receive this event.
I tried to implement this on the client side, but I got no callback Function call
Client:
void eventHandler(UA_Client* client, UA_UInt32 subId, void* subContext, UA_UInt32 monId, void* monContext,
                  size_t nEventFields, UA_Variant* eventFields)
{
    UA_LOG_INFO(UA_Log_Stdout, UA_LOGCATEGORY_USERLAND, "Event received");
}


   // Event Handling Setup
    // Create a subscription
    UA_CreateSubscriptionRequest request = UA_CreateSubscriptionRequest_default();
    UA_CreateSubscriptionResponse response = UA_Client_Subscriptions_create(client, request, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    // Set up a monitored item to receive events
    UA_NodeId eventTypeId = UA_NODEID_STRING(2, "CustomEvent");// Adjust as per your event type
    UA_MonitoredItemCreateRequest monRequest = UA_MonitoredItemCreateRequest_default(eventTypeId);
    UA_Client_MonitoredItems_createEvent(client, response.subscriptionId, UA_TIMESTAMPSTORETURN_BOTH, monRequest, NULL,
                                         eventHandler, NULL);

Server (NamespaceIndex is 2):
    UA_ObjectTypeAttributes attr = UA_ObjectTypeAttributes_default;
    attr.displayName = UA_LOCALIZEDTEXT("en-US", "CustomEvent");
    attr.description = UA_LOCALIZEDTEXT("en-US", "Event for ...");
    UA_Server_addObjectTypeNode(server, UA_NODEID_STRING(NamespaceIndex, "CustomEvent"),
                                UA_NODEID_NUMERIC(0, UA_NS0ID_BASEEVENTTYPE), UA_NODEID_NUMERIC(0, UA_NS0ID_HASSUBTYPE),
                                UA_QUALIFIEDNAME(NamespaceIndex, "CustomEvent"), attr, NULL, &eventType);


With UaExpert I can see the events from the server:

If someone knows what I am doint wrong on the client side, it would be very helpful
